# Error when i delete multiple rows "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Hey Everyone i am using this code to remove multiple records in table. but it's give me an error.

> "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager"

I am new in EF please help me what's wrong in my code.

> listOfEntities = list of record which i want to delete from table
>    U             = it is a type entity

```
using (var db = new DMContext())
{
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the entity is not attached. You can try like this

```
using (var db = new DMContext())
{
    db.YourTableEntity.Attach(EntityToRemove); 
    db.YourTableEntity.Remove(EntityToRemove);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You cannot remove the entities which are detached, so you need to first attach them and then you can remove it.

To remove multiple records

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    Set<T>().Remove(entity);
}

SaveChanges();
```

Comment: hey rahul i want to delete multiple records. and one thing i wanna tell u m using general method for deleting records.

Comment: how can i attach multiple entities

Comment: @A.Q:- Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: is that possible i can do that without using loop